# I get the error (fortran runtime error end of file) on Fortran, does anyone has an idea how can I solve it?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I work at gFortran. I encoded a file that will read data from a CSV file. The data is about matrix 1000000*10. I tried to compile it, unfortunately I get this error (Fortran runtime error: end of file) when I try to reduce the data size to 1000*100. It works fine. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: What version of gfortran? What operating system?  Is the file properly terminated?  Do  you have code that you would like to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of file errors mean that you're trying to keep reading past the end of the file.

With the little information you're giving us, this is all the help we can give.

Comment: Thank you, i figured out that i work in the wrong data sheet.